# MySQL 'OR' in 'WHERE' causes 'using filesort'

Tags: mysql

EXPLAINing the following query results in 'using where' (which as I understand is ok):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT niid
FROM news 
FORCE INDEX (ticker_market_date)
WHERE (ticker = "abcd" AND market = "") 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

However, if I add an 'OR' clause to my 'WHERE', I get 'using filesort':

```
EXPLAIN SELECT niid
FROM news 
FORCE INDEX (ticker_market_date)
WHERE (ticker = "abcd" AND market = "") 
OR (ticker = "abcd" AND market = "ef")
ORDER BY date DESC
```

How can I either create an index that will allow for multiple OR conditions (there will often be more than just the two that I've shown above), or how can I restructure my query to use my index? Or is there another way to optimize this?

Thank you.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your index `ticker_market_date` is on `(ticker, market, date)`, and assuming that `ticker = "abcd" AND market in ("", "ef")` is still highly selective, it seems that MySql might be getting the [query plan wrong](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/7-ways-to-convince-mysql-to-use-the-right-index) - `ORDER BY` is a common culprit here. What you could try is to nest the query such that the `ORDER BY` is applied last - this should allow you to drop the `FORCE INDEX`. If all of your filter predicates are of the same form, you can also clean them up into `IN` statements, although this is for readability and should have no impact on performance:

```
SELECT niid FROM
(
  SELECT niid, date
  FROM news 
  WHERE ticker = "abcd" AND market IN ("", "ef") 
) X
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Comment: Sorry about my extremely slow delay in a response, but this looks very promising. I'll be doing some query optimization in the coming months, I'll see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need an index that covers all the columns in all the sub-expressions of the `OR`. For the query you posted, you need:

```
ALTER TABLE news ADD INDEX (ticker, market);
```

Comment: This is already covered by my index ticker_market_date since ticker and market are the first two columns in the index.

Comment: I guess I swas supposed to guess that from the name of the index, but I didn't notice the `FORCE INDEX` clause. You asked how to create an index....